# Calling cancel() or purge on a locally created timer

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm just wondering how I could possibly call cancel or purge on a locally created timer, I.e., my timer is created on a button test:

```
        new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        int count = 0;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (count == 5) {
                lights[0].toggle();
                lights[1].toggle();
            } else if (count == 7) {
                lights[1].toggle();
                lights[2].toggle();
            } else if (count == 12) {
                lights[2].toggle();
                lights[0].toggle();
                count = 0;
                //Ideally, call cancel() or purge here
            }
            count++;
        }
    }).start();
```

How could i get the timer to cancel in the last if statement? trying to call cancel() or purger() attempts to call it on the Actionlistener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionEvent inherits a method for getting the object it occurred from.

```
...
else if (count == 12) {
    lights[2].toggle();
    lights[0].toggle();
    count = 0;
    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
}
```

`Cancel()` and `Purge()` are methods from `java.util.Timer`, `javax.swing.Timer` uses `Stop()`

Comment: This is actually a better solution than mine. +1.

Comment: Very useful, Just so I'm clear, this returns the timer as the timer is what is creating the event? Also if this was inside a buttonClick, it would return the button?

Comment: That's correct. If you look at the JavaDoc for [ActionEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html), you will see that it inherits `getSource()` from `EventObject`.  
`getSource()` returns an `Object` type (if you're unfamiliar with OOP I suggest looking up inheritance, or why it returns `Object` may not make sense) but Object doesn't define a `stop()` method (Timer does), so we have to cast it to a Timer class to call `stop()`. If you had a button you would cast it to a button and call whatever method you intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, null);
timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // ...
        timer.stop();
        // ...
    }
});
timer.start();
```

There is no `cancel()` or `purge()` method in Timer, so I demonstrated with `stop()`, which exists.